# How to make google, facebook authentication in django with flutter

Tags: django, api, flutter, django-rest-framework

I am using Flutter for a mobile app and django for backend API. I want user to be able to login with accounts from Facebook, Google etc. How Can I implement this?

Also I saw that dj-rest-auth provides requests for Social Media Authentication. Should I use something like this?

Comment: dj-rest-auth is built on top of [all-auth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html), which has support for a ton of social logins and JWT tokens. So yes, that's a good choice.

Comment: Did you found the answer? The answer that you have marked correct does not seem correct to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [flutter_facebook_login](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_login) package. You can use it like this:

```
import 'package:flutter_facebook_login/flutter_facebook_login.dart';

final facebookLogin = FacebookLogin();
final result = await facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email']);

switch (result.status) {
  case FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn:
    _sendTokenToServer(result.accessToken.token);
    _showLoggedInUI();
    break;
  case FacebookLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
    _showCancelledMessage();
    break;
  case FacebookLoginStatus.error:
    _showErrorOnUI(result.errorMessage);
    break;
}
```

And [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) package for the other part of your question. Here is a [complete example](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_sign_in/google_sign_in/example/lib/main.dart):

```
// Copyright 2019 The Flutter Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

// ignore_for_file: public_member_api_docs

import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert' show json;

import "package:http/http.dart" as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  scopes: <String>[
    'email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
  ],
);

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Google Sign In',
      home: SignInDemo(),
    ),
  );
}

class SignInDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => SignInDemoState();
}

class SignInDemoState extends State<SignInDemo> {
  GoogleSignInAccount _currentUser;
  String _contactText;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((GoogleSignInAccount account) {
      setState(() {
        _currentUser = account;
      });
      if (_currentUser != null) {
        _handleGetContact();
      }
    });
    _googleSignIn.signInSilently();
  }

  Future<void> _handleGetContact() async {
    setState(() {
      _contactText = "Loading contact info...";
    });
    final http.Response response = await http.get(
      'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections'
      '?requestMask.includeField=person.names',
      headers: await _currentUser.authHeaders,
    );
    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      setState(() {
        _contactText = "People API gave a ${response.statusCode} "
            "response. Check logs for details.";
      });
      print('People API ${response.statusCode} response: ${response.body}');
      return;
    }
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body);
    final String namedContact = _pickFirstNamedContact(data);
    setState(() {
      if (namedContact != null) {
        _contactText = "I see you know $namedContact!";
      } else {
        _contactText = "No contacts to display.";
      }
    });
  }

  String _pickFirstNamedContact(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    final List<dynamic> connections = data['connections'];
    final Map<String, dynamic> contact = connections?.firstWhere(
      (dynamic contact) => contact['names'] != null,
      orElse: () => null,
    );
    if (contact != null) {
      final Map<String, dynamic> name = contact['names'].firstWhere(
        (dynamic name) => name['displayName'] != null,
        orElse: () => null,
      );
      if (name != null) {
        return name['displayName'];
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  Future<void> _handleSignIn() async {
    try {
      await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }

  Future<void> _handleSignOut() => _googleSignIn.disconnect();

  Widget _buildBody() {
    if (_currentUser != null) {
      return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            leading: GoogleUserCircleAvatar(
              identity: _currentUser,
            ),
            title: Text(_currentUser.displayName ?? ''),
            subtitle: Text(_currentUser.email ?? ''),
          ),
          const Text("Signed in successfully."),
          Text(_contactText ?? ''),
          RaisedButton(
            child: const Text('SIGN OUT'),
            onPressed: _handleSignOut,
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: const Text('REFRESH'),
            onPressed: _handleGetContact,
          ),
        ],
      );
    } else {
      return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          const Text("You are not currently signed in."),
          RaisedButton(
            child: const Text('SIGN IN'),
            onPressed: _handleSignIn,
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Google Sign In'),
        ),
        body: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
          child: _buildBody(),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Akif thank you so much, if you know (or wrote) any article(s) or tutorial(s) on this topic, it would be great if you share the link(s). Specifically, I need to learn how to use google auth with Flutter without Firebase, in some details.

Answer (score 2):

try to use jwt which is JSON web token